# AngularJS Drag and Drop(drop-ang-drag-drop)

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, angular-dragdrop

I am trying drag and drop (ang-drag-drop)([github angular-drag-drop][1]) in angular. If receiver array is empty then example is not working.[plunkr][2].

```
[1]: http://angular-dragdrop.github.io/angular-dragdrop/
[2]: http://plnkr.co/edit/28BeMA4UGIA7CZ53VdmI?p=preview
```